# Centering NavigationBar

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want I want to make this nav bar centered in the middle of the screen and the li be centered respectively

Html

```
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/149.202.89.20:27015">US Server</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    ul.nav{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    height: 3.3em;
}

li.nav{
    float: left;
}

li a.nav{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For li.nav, remove float:left; and use this:

```
li.nav{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
ul.nav{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    height: 3.3em;
}

li.nav{
display: inline-block;
}

li a.nav{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/149.202.89.20:27015">US Server</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
</ul>
```